# Не распознается ни одно событие SDL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl2

Написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // для system
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    SDL_Event e;
    while (1) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            cout << 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Какую бы я клавишу не нажал, 1 не выводится в консоль. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: так вы даже систему эвентов не проинитили

Comment: если уж пишите на C++, так лучше взять SFML

Comment: Разве не достаточно указанного кода? На всех сайтах с курсами делалось примерно тоже. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @НикитаКаргин и где же это так же делалось?

Comment: Во-первых, нужно вызвать `SDL_Init`. Во-вторых, создать окно.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // для system
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Event e;
    while (1) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            cout << 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Необходимо было инициализировать SDL2.